# array_push and array_search array_splice on Laravel query builder

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, pdo, query-builder

Are there any other eloquent query method to deal with the gross process on laravel query builder?

product table

```
id  A_product   B_product           
1   4,5,8,9     3,7,10,15
2   4,7,10,11   2,3,5,13
```

which is better does A_product column use array or json?

----search--------------------------------------

if I want to confirm if is there 3 in A_product column on id 1
I use:

```
$querys=DB::table('product')
->where('id','=','1')
->value('A_product');

if(in_array("3"){
 $A_result='1';
}else{
 $A_result='0';
};
```

------insert----------------------------

if I want to add new num 20 to the A_product column
I use:

```
$querys=DB::table('product')
  ->where('id','=','1')
  ->value('A_product');

array_push($querys,"20");
$quearorder=array_value($querys);
DB::table('product')
 ->where('id', 1)
 ->update(['A_product' => $queryorder]);
```

--delete--------------------------------------

if I want to delete num 3 from the A_product column
I use:

```
$querys=DB::table('product')
->where('id','=','1')
->value('A_product');

$key=array_search(3,$querys);

array_splice($querys,$key,1); 

DB::table('product')
 ->where('id', 1)
 ->update(['A_product' => $querys]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its suggestion that you should store all product into separate column , with product type and the group or for user_id

```
id  product product_type  category(or for user)
1   4             A                       1
2   5             A                       1
3   8             A                       1
4   9             A                       1
5   4             A                       2
6   7             A                       2
7   10           A                       2
8   11           A                       2
1   3             B                       1
2   7             B                      1
3   10           B                       1
4   15           B                       1
5   2             B                       2
6   3             B                      2
7   5             B                      2
8   13           B                       2
```

Then you can easily apply CRUD operation

Comment: I found the sql have a column called ENUM SET and The JSON Data Type. Cannot use for this purpose?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html